# Getting the same stat values when I split dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantitative-finance

I am just reading in data from a csv 
and when I try to separate the dataframe between buy and dont buy
I keep getting the same values for things like mean and sharpe ratio, am I dropping something wrong.

```
df_buy= df.copy()
df_buy.drop(df_buy[(df_buy.Signal=='Dont 
Buy')].index, inplace=True)

df_dont_buy= df.copy()

df_dont_buy.drop(df_dont_buy
[(df_dont_buy.Signal=='Dont 
Buy')].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you show what your dataframes look like and explain in words how you are trying to separate them?

Comment: Looks like you are filtering both the dataframes on same condition, 'Don't Buy'

Comment: my dataframe is just a nvidia download from yahoo finance so ohlcv, I am separating the values after doing a rolling mean if current volume > average volume.

Comment: when I try to run the sharpe ratio on the separate dataframes I get the same values, same thing for the mean of the dataframes

Comment: this is what I thought the code might look like assigning the dropped values to another dataframe          df_buy= df.copy()
df_b=df_buy.drop(df_buy[(df_buy.Signal=='Dont Buy')].index, inplace=True)

df_dont_buy= df.copy()
df_db=df_dont_buy.drop(df_dont_buy[(df_dont_buy.Signal=='Dont Buy')].index, inplace=True) but I keep getting object not subscriptable

Comment: Can we post a proper answer please?

Answer (score 0):

thanks Vaishali, 
I made the same mistake for the sharpe ratio formulas as well